# how to get product attribute set in phtml file

Tags: magento2

I want attribute set name in phtml file in magento2 and display it in product page
[image]

i want to display it in below page

Comment: have you create a attribute name is  ? and want to show in detail page ?

Comment: i have created from admin in attribute and selectin sttribute name in product page

Comment: $product    = $this->_productRepository->get("PRODUCTSKU");
 $attributes    = $product->getAttributes();
 $attributes    = $product->getAttribute('certified_icons');
 $abc          = $product->getAttributeText('certified_icons '); //certified_icons is artibute name
       
 echo $abc;

Answer (score 1):

Try below code to get the **attribute Set** in phtml file.

```
/** @var \Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeSetRepositoryInterface $attributeSet **/
protected $attributeSet;

public function __construct(
    ......
    \Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeSetRepositoryInterface $attributeSet
    ......
) {
   ......
   $this->attributeSet = $attributeSet;
}


//Build method to get attribute set
public function getAttributeSetName() {

    $product = $this->getProduct();
    $attributeSetRepository = $this->attributeSet->get($product->getAttributeSetId());
    return $attributeSetRepository->getAttributeSetName();
}
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: not working in phtml file

Comment: @Ashish Ramchandani , Manthan Dave is define the function on code for block class  not phtml files. It means on your phtml's files block class, you have to inject this class  and  added the function `getAttributeSetName`  and after that on phtml your  have to call `getAttributeSetName` by using code `$block->getAttributeSetName()`